# Python - string into list without punctuation

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file with a sentence and I need to make a function that splits the sentence into a list with the words as elements but removing all punctuation.
This is what I have:

```
def listWords(filename):
    sentence = []
    
    file = open(filename, "r")
    line = file.read()

    line = line.translate(str.maketrans(' ', ' ', '".,())'))
    for word in line.split():
        sentence.append(word.lower())

    file.close()
    return sentence
```

It's close to working but there's a hyphenated word that just gets put together as one word and I need it split. Also decimal numbers like 1,2 get split like this ["1", "2"] and I don't want that.

Is there a better way to go around this? Maybe a simpler solution? I think it may be intented to use string.punctuation but I'm not sure how that would fix these problems

Comment: So what should become of "semi-sweet"?

Comment: it should be ["semi", "tweet"], two words in a list

Comment: Any concerns about contractions? e.g. Should "can't" be split into ['can','t']?

Comment: not a problem in the language the sentence is in

Answer (score 3):

Nltk is a great tool for natural language processing. You can also use regular expressions together with nltk.tokenize to tokenize your text as you wish. The following regular expression means any alphanumeric character repeated any number of times :

```
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')

print(tokenizer.tokenize("I. love - stack ! overflow so 1, 2 much! "))
```

Output:
['I', 'love', 'stack', 'overflow', 'so', '1', '2', 'much']

Comment: Probably not the easiest way, but the best one for sure.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the import, maybe it's something I'm not supposed to use in the answer or just not supported in the context I am working in. I'm not accepting the answer just yet in case someone has a simpler solution but thank you so much!

Comment: When you install nltk, you actually install only the classes but not the corpora. The corpora are considered too large to be included. When you import the module for the first time, you need to call function download() (you need an internet connection for that) and install the missing parts. In your case, the missing part is nltk.tokenize

Comment: I have to submit the function in a platform that then runs it with different examples to check if it's right, I don't have enough control to do all that I think

Comment: If nltk is still not working for you, you can use a regular expressions directly to solve your problem: re.findall(r'\w+',"I. love - stack ! overflow so 1, 2 much! ")). This will give you the same list as aforementioned but without the use of nltk module

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that removes punctuation from a list or string--whichever is passed. Like so:

```
In[]: dirty_str_ex = 'Th$$is. is! a? !very-dirty$$ str@@ing'

In[]: def remove_punc(data): 
          punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
          if isinstance(data,str) == True:
              for i in data:  
                  if i in punc:  
                      data = data.replace(i, "")
           elif isinstance(data,list) == True:
              data = [remove_punc(i) for i in data]
          return data

In[]: remove_punc(dirty_str_ex)
Out[]: 'Thisisaverydirtystring'

In[]: dirty_str_lst = dirty_str_ex.split() ; print(dirty_str_lst) #splits str to lst of strings
Out[]: ['Th$$is.', 'is!', 'a?', '!very-dirty$$', 'str@@ing']

#pass the dirty list of strings to remove punctuation

In[]: remove_punc(dirty_str_lst)
Out[]: ['This', 'is', 'a', 'verydirty', 'string']
```

Comment: It seems I can do all that with the translate() I already have and in your example "very-dirty" still was saved in the list as just one word so that wouldn't work